# unixodbc with php command works but apache2 fail

Tags: php, apache, unixodbc

I've installed unixodbc, freetds, php on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-44-generic i686) and I get my query works fine with:

```
php /var/www/connect.php
```

but when access to **localhost/connect.php** I get:

```
Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect in /var/www/connect.php on line 8 Warning: odbc_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/connect.php on line 10 Warning: odbc_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/connect.php on line 11 Warning: odbc_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/connect.php on line 15
```

I think is about permissions.